# Python skip empty cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to search through my dataframe and skip cells that are blank. However, when i read in the DF it reads the blanks as "nan"

DF1

```
Name Address1 Street      Town   Postcode
Will nan      nan        London   nan
Phil 19      Long Road     nan    nan
```

I want to be able to filter through Address1, Street and Town. If there is text inside of those columns I want to add a "|" at the start but if there is no text inside of the column it skips that cell and doesn't add the "|"

Desired Result

```
Name Address1 Street      Town   Postcode
Will                     |London 
Phil 19      |Long Road
```

Comment: In each pands DataFrame `'cell'` has to be some value, so need replace `nan` to empty string? Because if need `skips that cell` it is impossible.

Comment: in the above output, when Street is empty there's no "|", and when it's not there is a "|". Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Is there away I can filter through them so if it contains text then add the | if not dont?

Comment: `If there is text inside of those columns I want to add a "|" at the start` - so why removed from `London`  ?

Comment: not fast but should work: `df.applymap(lambda x: '|'+x if type(x)==str else x)`

Comment: add `|19` for match accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np
for i in ['Address1','Street','Town']:
    df[i] = np.where(df[i].notnull(),'|' + df[i].astype(str),'')
```

Which prints:

```
print(df)

   Name Address1       Street     Town  Postcode
0  Will                        |London       nan
1  Phil    |19.0  |Long Road                nan
```

Comment: It is clearly wrong. Check expected output

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Am I missing something in what he wants?

Comment: it is unclear why not `|London`, but `|19` is wrong, also `nan` is neceserry remove

Comment: Okay I think I am not understanding his question then. Not very clearly written.

Comment: agree, it was reason why ask under question

Comment: Apologies edited the wrong thing. This works perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

So what I can recommend is looking into the [Pandas Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). According to the docs, you can use the `pd.read_csv()` function with additional parameters to decide what to do with the `NaN` values.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("sample.csv", sep=";", keep_default_na=False)
```

So according to the docs this could be a sample solution. :)

> If keep_default_na is False, and na_values are not specified, no strings will be parsed as NaN.

Answer (score 1):

changing @sophods 's solution to remove NaN values.

```
import numpy as np
for i in ['Address1','Street','Town']:
    df[i] = np.where(df[i].notnull(),'|' + df[i].astype(str),'')
```

Comment: @sophods np.where is pretty fast isn't it? been using it instead of loops :D

Answer (score 0):

simple way to add  "|"

```
for row in data 
   for i in row
      if i != ''
      i = "|" + i
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when two cells in a row have a value, you want to put `|`?

here is the code:

```
for r, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if i>1 and row[i]!=None and row[i-1]!=None:
            df.at[r,col[i]] = '|' + str(row[i])
```

here is the result:

```
Name    Address1     Street     Town    Postcode
Will     None        None       London   None
Phil    19.0      |Long Road    None    None
```

I build my dataframe by None. change `None` with your `nan`

Comment: Would i need to change col for my columns?

Comment: col is a list of columns name here `col = ['Name','Address1', 'Street', 'Town', 'Postcode']` @Will .